# Why was the "channel name" question deleted so quickly?

Tags: discussion

I'm asking this out of genuine curiosity and not advocating or evangelizing for any action.

A question recently appeared on the front page, and was deleted 10 minutes later.

#### [Why is it spelled "*channel name*" instead of "*channel's name*"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239191/why-is-it-spelled-channel-name-instead-of-channels-name)

[image: Screenshot of deleted question for non-10K users]

The question was fairly ordinary, but I could see how it might have attracted an interesting answer from one of our resident linguists. In any case, nothing stuck out about it to me that called for deletion; it certainly wasn't offensive. There weren't even any comments on it except a quick one I shot off asking for more context.

Does anyone know why this question was deleted, and so quickly?

<sub>Again, I'm not asking for your undelete votes, because I don't know if the question was deleted for a good reason.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the deletion message. There are only two ways that a single user can delete a question: one is if they are a moderator; the other is that the asker removes his own question.

That's what happened here. There's no diamond, so it's a self-deletion.

What is slightly odd is that, having also deleted their account (hence the grey/unlinked user name under the question), the old username is still used in the deletion message.

Comment: But the question says "*asked by **user117208***" and the deletion message says "*deleted by **naf***".  Did he link his named account to his anonymous account, and then delete both, as well as his question on EL&U, all in a span of 10 minutes? I did try searching for both these users, but I don't know how to productively search for a user when I only know their display name and not their numeric ID. Also, I was able to undelete-vote it: should I be able to do that for a self-deleted question (I honestly don't know).

Comment: Er, yes. "It is slightly odd that ... the old username is still used in the deletion message." The numeric id is 117208. (If the system allows you to vote to undelete, then you can.)